# General Special Unitary matrix in 2D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, time, unitarity

I have been looking to find a derivation showing that any 2D special unitary operator can be written as:
$$ \hat{U}= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta)& e^{i\gamma}\sin(\theta)\\
-e^{-i\gamma}\sin(\theta)& \cos(\theta)
             \end{bmatrix}. $$
I have not had any luck thus far, but my reasoning until now went like this:
I define a unitary $U$:

$$   U = \left[\begin{matrix}U_{1} & U_{2} \\U_{3} & U_{4} \end{matrix}\right] \label{UUunit}
$$

Since we defined the above matrix as unitary, one can say $UU^\dagger=UU^{-1}\Rightarrow U^\dagger =U^{-1}$:

$$
     U^\dagger = \left[\begin{matrix}U_{1}^* & U_{3}^* \\U_{2}^* & U_{4}^*\end{matrix}\right] =  U^{-1} = \frac{1}{det(U)}\left[\begin{matrix}U_{4} & -U_{2} \\-U_{3} & U_{1}\end{matrix}\right]
$$

We restrict $U$ with $det(U)=U_1U_4 - U_2U_3 =1$.
The above equation then gives the relation $U_1 = U_4^*$ and $U_2 = -U_3^*$, while from $UU^\dagger = 1$ we obtain three different identities

$$
    |U_{1}|^{2} + |U_{2}|^{2} = 1 \\
    |U_{3}|^{2} + |U_{4}|^{2}= 1 \\
    U_{1} U_{3}^* + U_{2} U_{4}^*= 0 \\
$$
Tuplets of numbers $\{U_i,U_j\}$ that satisfy the above relations can be parametrized as $U_i = e^{i\mu_i}\cos(\theta)$ and $U_j = e^{i \gamma_j}\sin(\theta)$ (for $\gamma,\theta, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$).\
Applying all the constraints found until now, one gets:
$$
    U_1 = e^{i\mu} \cos(\theta)\\
    U_4 = e^{-i\mu} \cos(\theta)\\
    U_2 = e^{i\gamma} \sin(\theta)\\
    U_3 = -e^{-i\gamma} \sin(\theta)\\
$$

My problem with this is the presence of 3 angles $\mu, \gamma, \theta$; while the general description requires only two.
What am I missing?

Comment: Have you considered that the overall operator is only specified up to a global phase?

Comment: Do you mean there is some way I could extract the third angle $\mu$ by making it become some global shift?

Answer (score 3):

Surely you recognize $\operatorname{diag}[e^{i\phi},e^{-i\phi}]$ is unitary unimodular but not of the $\hat U$ form.

Your derivation is fine, but, to avoid confusion, call the *U* you found *V*, and your independent parameter *γ* by *γ-μ*, instead. Thus, you found the unitary, unimodular
$$ V= \begin{bmatrix}
e^{i\mu} \cos(\theta)& e^{i(\gamma-\mu)}\sin(\theta)\\
-e^{-i(\gamma-\mu)}\sin(\theta)& e^{-i\mu} \cos(\theta)
             \end{bmatrix}= M\hat{U}M, $$
for
$$ M= \begin{bmatrix}
e^{i\mu/2} &  0\\
 0& e^{-i\mu/2}  
             \end{bmatrix},
$$
unitary and unimodular as well. In your group SU(2), which has 3 parameters, *μ*  specifies the orientation of the *x* and *y* axes you choose on that plane.

It should be instructive to read up on sundry [parameterizations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix#2_%C3%97_2_unitary_matrix) of unitary matrices (set *φ=0*).

---

*Note addressing your comment, arguably*:

From your language, it appears you are thinking of some type of Bloch matrix "effectively" invariant under a rotation preserving the *z*-axis,
$$
M^\dagger \hat U M  =\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(\theta)& e^{i(\gamma-\mu)}\sin(\theta)\\
-e^{-i(\gamma-\mu)}\sin(\theta)&   \cos(\theta)
             \end{bmatrix} ~,
$$
where I am using your *original*, not the above, shifted parameter! That is, the $\hat U$ I'm handling above is this very matrix, so your original $\hat U= V M^{-2}$. If you are using your   $\hat U$  to dot on a lower component of a two-spinor to represent a most general 2-spinor (qubit), then you are allowed this rotation at the very start, and *μ* is fictitious/redundant, given the arbitrariness of the absolute phase.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure I understand, but from your V how would I go around finding the unitary in the same form as the one presented in the original post?

Comment: $\hat U$, *M*, and *V* are all unitary, related as above. You can invert *M* and take it to the left, around *V*. But the original unitary matrix is not the most general *SU(2)* group element. You found it.

Comment: I am sure that is the unitary I am supposed to find. I am using it to time evolve a density operator: does this information help?

Answer (score 0):

As Cosmas Zachos has pointed out, the general form for a 2D special unitary operator you give in your post is in fact *not* the most general matrix. You won't have any luck proving this, because it is not true. The matrix you did find *is* the most general.